# Determining the Problematic CSS File in Firebug

Tags: css, firebug

I have this displayed in my Firebug console

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://********.com/images/slider-img/ajax-loader.gif"

So it's telling me it can't find a background image. But can it pinpoint which CSS file this image has been declared as a background-image property?

I have about 4-5 CSS files being referenced in the document and the manual way of finding it out would to open each of the files and find for this image. So I was wondering if this could be avoided and have Firebug tell me which CSS file is the culprit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug currently (as of version 2.0.x) doesn't directly show you the initiator of a network request. This requires platform support, which is requested in [bug 563623](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563623).

So, as a workaround you can do this:

1. Switch to the *CSS* panel.
2. Click into the search field at the right side of Firebug.
3. Ensure that the option *Multiple Files* is checked.
4. Enter `ajax-loader.gif`

=> The *CSS* panel will switch to the CSS source containing the rule containing the image value.

Notes:
There may be several properties referring to different images named `ajax-loader.gif`. So you should also check whether the path to the image corresponds to the one shown in the error message. (Within the search field you can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get to the next match.)

It's not sure that the request comes from CSS. It may also come from JavaScript, e.g. through an AJAX request or by appending an `<img>` tag dynamically.